# Upload Image without Page Refresh & then Display Image

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a button that allows a user to select an image - shown below:

```
        <div id="fileUpload">
          <form id="joinPhotoUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="file"/>
          </form>
          <div id="fakefile">
            <img src="../../images/button-grey-enhanced.png" id="usePhotoSubmit" alt="BROWSE for Photo">
            <span id="usePhoto">BROWSE</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I then need to upload the image to the server and display the image on the same page without a page refresh. I've tried the following:

```
$('input#file').change(function() {
  $('form#joinPhotoUploadForm').submit();
});
```

Any advise on how I can get the image upload and displayed on the same page without a page refresh?

thx

Comment: You're going to need an AJAX call, not a form submission... or rather, not a form submission like that.  Take a look at `$.post()`.

Comment: You can use AJAX as @JeremyHolovacs suggested or you could simply use an iframe if your desire for no page refresh is purely aesthetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the solution provided in this tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC7C25B2F18F68F3EF&feature=plcp

Answer (score 1):

You could use the FileReader and File API available in modern browsers to read the file client side before uploading it and display a preview then allow the user upload after they've verified the preview. You can also implement drag and drop with an image from their desktop to the browser instead of a traditional file select input.

Here is a tutorial for it: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

In older browsers you can just fall back to a traditional file input with a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a fancy uploader like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) or [Pupload](http://www.plupload.com/)?

Comment: I want to avoid flash cause of the iphone factor... does pupload support IE7 & 8?

Comment: Both can use html5 (in fact the Uploadify html 5 version is not free but costs 5 bucks).
I'm almost sure it does.